# Create a Style for buttons

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, button, styles

What is the best solution for creating a style resource for using with Buttons which includes Button color , background , text style and size and color , rounded edges in android studio 3.6.2.

i want it to be suitable for API's level from 19 and up

i tried to use a one like mentioned in Udacity Course but it seems doesn't work for the button color:

```
  <style name="SleepButtons" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white_text_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/green_color</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

youshould create a xml file in drawable like button_background

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50dp"></corners>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@android:color/white"></stroke>
    <padding android:right="2dp" android:left="2dp"></padding>
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/colorAccent" android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary" android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

then write this to button

```
android:background="@drawable/button_background"
```